# A l'époque de Proust, que signifie "P.P.C" sur une carte de visite ?

Tags: abréviations

Je trouve, en lisant *A l'ombre des jeunes filles en fleur* :

> J'ai rencontré Taine qui m'a dit que la Princesse était brouillée avec
> lui, dit Swann. – Il s'est conduit comme un cauchon », dit-elle d'une
> voix rude et en prononçant le mot comme si ç'avait été le nom de
> l'évêque contemporain de Jeanne d'Arc. « Après l'article qu'il a écrit
> sur l'Empereur je lui ai laissé une carte avec P.P.C. »

([source](https://alarecherchedutempsperdu.org/marcelproust/123))

Que signifie cette abréviation "P.P.C" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Autrement dit: elle supporte le dénigrement du personnage Napoléon, mais pas celui du bonapartisme. Décidant de marquer son indignation de façon
> définitive, elle lui fait porter par un serviteur sa carte de visite,
> chez lui, rue Cassette, portant les fameuses lettres P.P.C. **pour
> prendre congé**. Ces lettres étaient aussi traduites dans le milieu
> littéraire de façon plus drôle : Princesse Pas Contente. Taine, dont
> le sens de l’humour n’était peut-être pas le fort, prend acte, et ne
> fait aucun commentaire. Les Origines ne faisaient qu’une mécontente de
> plus…

Trouvé dans une thèse de doctorat: [P.P.C.](http://www.theses.fr/2013PA010640.pdf)

Comment: L'explication, que je n'ai pas pris le temps d'approfondir est en effet éclairante.

Answer (score 3):

C'est l’abréviation de « porté par courrier », utilisé quand on remet un courrier en mains propres sans passer par un service de distribution officiel (comme La Poste). Je ne pense pas que ce soit encore très employé de nos jours.

Une autre signification, et ça pourrait bien être celle exprimée par Proust ici se trouve dans le [Larousse Universel](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58490121/f664.item) en 2 volumes (1923)

> « P.P.C. » abréviation des mots *Pour Prendre Congé*, mise sur les cartes de visite qu'on laisse chez les personnes à qui l'on rend visite avant de partir en voyage, de changer de résidence, etc. et qu'on ne trouve pas chez elle.

ce qui semble probable dans le contexte.

Comment: Merci ! C'était une question purement historique : je ne comprenais pas ce passage de la Recherche.

Comment: Normalement, on indiquerait cela à la personne qui l'a trouvé pour qu'elle puisse modifier sa réponse. Ou au moins le dire lorsqu'on le prend pour soi.